# Many to one or many to many

Tags: logic, grammatical-number

> Record A is linked to case 1
>   Record B is linked to case 2
>   Record C is linked to case 3

*Which of the following sentences is correct?*

- There are 3 records linked to a case
- There are 3 records linked to cases

Comment: Neither is semantically "correct," but both are grammatically acceptable. Avoid such ambiguity. *There are 3 records linked to a case **each**.* or *There are 3 records linked to **respective** cases*. Merely choosing between singular and plural will not serve in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but neither unequivocally expresses the information. To be unambiguous, you could say

> There are three records, *each* linked to a *different* case.

The problems with your offered contructions are as follows:  the first could mean three records are linked to one case; the second could mean that each of the records is linked to one or more cases.

Comment: There are many ways to say the same thing, but the OP's examples are not adequate.